# Chrome is not changing the parent div size as dynamic content grow ? Firefox and IE is working fine

Tags: google-chrome, html, cross-browser, dynamic-content

I am using a jquery and php script to load dynamic content on the page .Mozilla is picking up the dynamic ontent and increasing size of div as well .Below are the code.

```
#whtshot{width:700px; min-height:200px; height:auto !important; background:blue;position:relative; padding-bottom: 500px; clear:both;left:10px;top:200px; }  

.newsbox{width:640px;height:460px;position:relative;margin:auto;top:10px;background:white;box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888;}

#transbox {width:1305px; height:auto !important;min-height:212;clear:both;background:rgb(250, 250, 250);position:relative;margin:auto;opacity:1;filter:alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */box-shadow:0 0 10px #9ecaed;}
```

Transbox is wrapper,whtshot is container for newsbox
[here is the link](http://werecommends.com/news.php) where page is check it out

On adding Overflow:hidden to transbox.. is not scrolling in google chrome.....?? Mozilla and IE is OK.

Answer (score 0):

## transbox{overflow:hidden} ----------- it will work , but be sure it will not hamper other, One more thing , you have user too much ( !important ) , for best practice don't use.

Comment: Thnks I have done the change u said ,but if turns-off the scrolling of page in google crome ,but still working nice with firefox... thnx for firefox but i need it to work on google chrome ... plz help me with it

Comment: you can see the link given for change